# Give group permission to only kill specific process which is started by root

Tags: kill

I want the members of a certain group to kill python.

`pidof python | xargs kill`

This is no problem when python has been started by themself. But when root has started a python process than the users of the group can't kill python.

I can fix this to allow the group members to use `kill` without password.

`%nohup ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/kill`

But now the group members can kill each process. I only want them to kill python.

How can I give permission to a group to kill only a specific proces that has been started by root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend writing a shell script that is allowed with NOPASSWD that simply contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
killall python
#pkill could also have been used
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: remove the kill authority, put your kill command that kills your specific process in a shell script, make the owner of the script be root, and set the group authority for the script to be a new group containing the authorized users.

Comment: The OP states that `kill` cannot be used as it requires a non-static parameter.